# Allocated heap memory and drawables of different size

Tags: android

I'm tracking allocated heap memory on my app and at maximum it's 15.5MB. Most of this comes from bitmaps. I have a folder named "drawable" that I place all my bitmaps in, so all devices will load the same bitmaps, no matter screen size. Test device is Desire HD. My question is: When a small screen device runs my app, will it allocate the same amount of memory? (keep in mind that I don't have smaller bitmaps for small screen devices).

The reason I'm doubting is that no matter what it's resized to, it comes from the same resource. For instance, I have found that drawing a 400*800 bitmap and drawing a 300*600 bitmap consumes different amounts of memory even though I strech them both to fill the screen.

If I use smaller bitmaps for small screen devices, I assume it will allocate less memmory. It's just that I have like 300 bitmaps and I'm trying to avoid the pain of having to copy and reduce the size of 300 bitmaps.

Another question while I'm at it: I read somewhere that the lowest maximum heap size is 16MB. Is this still true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bitmaps will be resized automatically based on [inDensity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inDensity) and [inTargetDensity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inTargetDensity).
This is of course slower than having multiple versions of the same bitmap but in your case it might be the best choice.

Comment: I know they will be resized. Actually, I'm resizing them myself when I draw them on canvas. The question is: Will it consume less memory on a small screen device? The reason I'm doubting is that no matter what it's resized to, it comes from the same resource. For instance, I have found that drawing a 400*800 bitmap and drawing a 300*600 bitmap consumes different amounts of memory even though I strech them both to fill the screen.

Comment: Resizing bitmaps when you draw them is a pretty bad idea. It's slow and a waste of memory if draw it smaller. You should resize it when you load it so it has exactly the size you draw it and consumes as much memory as required for drawing.

Comment: I don't resize when I draw bitmaps, I resize them once, and then draw.

Comment: That's not the problem. I'm asking a question that has nothing to do with my particular code. Given the following assumptions: 1. The same bitmaps are used on all devices. 2. The bitmaps are manually scaled to fit all screen sizes. The question is: Will my bitmaps consume less memory on a small screen device, than on a large screen device?

Comment: Yes... in case it's done right. (The bitmaps are not scaled for size but for pixel density)